# Sound not being recognized by InfoCenter

Tags: ios, swift, media-player, media, spotify

I've searched for a problem like this but I didn't find an answer. Whenever I play a sound in my app the InfoCenter does not recognize there is a sound playing. I have tried to display song metadata but it will not work on device, but will work in simulator.

Does anyone know what may be keeping my Song from displaying in InfoCenter?

Comment: what is audio format and encoding and bitrate etc?

Comment: I am using Spotify so i guess OGG.. And according to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613581/what-audio-format-spotify-uses-and-how-they-transfer-the-files-to-mobile-devices bit rate is either 96, 160 or 320 kbit/sec.

Comment: Either way, if i use a local MP3 it will not appear.